# UV Coordinates Not Correct

Tags: opengl, 3ds

I am using Cheetah3D if it mattters.

The UV coordinates I am reading in my object made in Cheetah3D are NOT between 0 and 1 like the example model I was provided with the 3DS model object loading code.

Some go above 1 as high as 1.56 or so while others go below 0, as far as -4.56. This is causing extreme abnormalities when trying to map the texture to the object.

Any ideas? Should I contact the Cheetah3D folks or is there a way to fix this in code myself dynamically? (The reason for posting on SO).

Comment: You may just want to try normalizing the coordinates before making any drastic changes.

Comment: texture coordinates out of the [0-1] range are perfectly valid if the texture is to repeat on the model.

Answer (score 1):

Well without seeing screenshots the only thing that comes to mind is that the texture cords should be wrapped but you're clamping them. See the documentation for glTexParameter* on how to change that setting. A screenshot of a SIMPLE model would really help here.

Comment: The array of structs that contain the UV vectors is the problem not my generation of the texture. Models I've gotten for the net and the sample one all have vertices for the UV mapping that lie between 0 and 1.

Comment: The thing is addressing outside the 0,1 range for UV coordinates is perfectly valid behavior.  Have you at least tried setting the texture addressing mode to wrap?